# Moving from 12.04 beta to 12.04 final, now I have 12.10?

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, beta

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“No new release found” when upgrading a from 10.04 LTS to 12.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125392/no-new-release-found-when-upgrading-a-from-10-04-lts-to-12-04-lts)
>   [ubuntu 12.04 reports itself as quantal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126498/ubuntu-12-04-reports-itself-as-quantal)

I installed the 12.04 beta some time ago. After the final version was released, I consulted "the internet", which told me ([here](https://superuser.com/questions/415187/is-it-possible-to-upgrade-ubuntu-12-04-beta-2-to-final-without-reinstalling) ) that I do not need to do anything, I'll have 12.04 final at the time it is released.

However, now it seems I have 12.10 development version installed, at least that's what `lsb_release -a` tells me...

I'm wondering what's the correct procedure to go from beta to final, and what can I do now to go back to 12.04 final without a complete reinstall?

Thanks!

EDIT:

```
$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu quantal (development branch) \n \l
```

Comment: related question -> http://askubuntu.com/questions/126498/ubuntu-12-04-reports-itself-as-quantal