# Software & updates not opening in ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.04, 13.10, software-updater

I entered `sudo software-properties-gtk` on terminal but software & updates not opened.
And this command (`sudo software-properties-gtk`) shows this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/software-properties-gtk", line 101, in <module>
    app = SoftwarePropertiesGtk(datadir=options.data_dir, options=options, file=file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/gtk/SoftwarePropertiesGtk.py", line 98, in __init__
    SoftwareProperties.__init__(self, options=options, datadir=datadir)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 109, in __init__
    self.reload_sourceslist()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 599, in reload_sourceslist
    self.distro.get_sources(self.sourceslist)    
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptsources/distro.py", line 89, in get_sources
    (self.id, self.codename))
aptsources.distro.NoDistroTemplateException: Error: could not find a distribution template for Ubuntu/trusty .
```

Also I want to mention that just few day before i upgrade from ubuntu 13.04 to ubuntu 13.10.
And also shows 14.04 error rather than 13.10 ....
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `could not find a distribution template for Ubuntu/trusty` - Problems with the development version of Ubuntu are off topic - you should report a bug instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem.
Just change the `lsr-release` info using the following steps:

1. Go to the Terminal and type the following:

   ```
   gksudo gedit /etc/lsb-release
   ```
2. Edit the file so that you get the following:

   ```
   DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu

   DISTRIB_RELEASE=13.10

   DISTRIB_CODENAME=saucy

   DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu Saucy Salamander"
   ```

Note: This solution is optimized from the following answer [Apt "could not find a distribution template" error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49040/apt-could-not-find-a-distribution-template-error)