# Ubuntu thinks I'm using 14.04

Tags: system-installation

I've run into various problems because my Ubuntu distro (which is the newest Ubuntu GNOME 13.10 distro) thinks it's using Ubuntu 14.04.
To check this, I entered:

```
$ lsb_release -a
```

This got me:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu Trusty Tahr (development branch)
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

However, this is NOT the Ubuntu version I am (or want to be, as for now) running.

One of the problems I'm running into is the fact that `software-properties-gtk` is crashing when I try to start it, and I get the error:

```
Sorry, Ubuntu 14.04 experienced an internal error
```

When I try to run `software-properties-gtk` in my terminal, I get:

```
aptsources.distro.NoDistroTemplateException: Error: could not find a distribution template for Ubuntu/trusty
```

which is strange. Any thoughts on the matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check your /etc/apt/sources.list and check if it's saucy or trusty in there. If it's saucy it should contain 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu saucy main restricted'.... and if trusty 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main restricted'

Comment: Ah, I just found a solution here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/49040/apt-could-not-find-a-distribution-template-error

Comment: @hankruiger Does that answer your complete question then?

Comment: That will make the error go away, but will not be very helpful if you did actually upgrade to trusty at some point. If you actually do have trusty packages installed, then you may already have some newer packages installed, which could potentially block any updates that may go to saucy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. Trying to install kali sources to ubuntu 14.04, the "lsb-release" file was modified.

I just :

```
gksudo gedit /etc/lsb-release
```

and paste the original distribution information you are using, in my case Ubuntu 14.04

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
```

I hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I see is to reinstall the system. Ubuntu doesn't support downgrades between versions of Ubuntu (downgrade of individual packages, yes) the same way Debian doesn't. You must do a backup of your system and reinstall everything again.