# Installing Java on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: java

I'm installing Java on Ubuntu 15.10 when I typed `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java` The result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 95, in <module>
    sp = SoftwareProperties(options=options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 109, in __init__
    self.reload_sourceslist()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 599, in reload_sourceslist
    self.distro.get_sources(self.sourceslist)    
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptsources/distro.py", line 89, in get_sources
    (self.id, self.codename))
aptsources.distro.NoDistroTemplateException: Error: could not find a distribution template for Ubuntu/xenial
```

how to fix it? thank you

Comment: `xenial` is 16.04. Are you on 15.10 or 16.04?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Java?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/48468/how-do-i-install-java)

Comment: I use Ubuntu 15.10

Comment: What is the output of `cat /etc/lsb-release`?

Comment: shiroemon@shiroemon:~$ cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu Xenial Xerus (development branch)"

Comment: Then you have upgraded to 16.04 somehow.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apt "could not find a distribution template" error](http://askubuntu.com/questions/49040/apt-could-not-find-a-distribution-template-error)

Answer (score 0):

For now on Xenial 16.04 use [this](http://tutorialforlinux.com/2016/02/14/how-to-install-oracle-jdk-7-on-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-32-64bit-linux-easy-visual-guide/) guide for installing java. 
Hopefully the webupd8team will add the Xenial distribution to the ppa. After the ppa update it will be possible to install via [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-java-on-ubuntu-with-apt-get).

Comment: thank you. but when I typed 
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javaws javaws /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_80/bin/javaws 1065
it notified update-alternatives: error: alternative path /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_80/bin/javaws doesn't exist

Comment: make sure you did the previous steps and check whether there is javaws executable in the /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_80/bin/ path by   ls /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_80/bin/java*   .  This should output following: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_80/bin/javaws