# Help ! Lubuntu thinks it is Trisquel

Tags: lubuntu, repository

I am a newbie. I have had lubuntu for about 6 months with no problems. Recently tried to check out the gnu icecat browser. I added a repo from Trisquel to download the browser...but there appears to have some kind of a problem with Lubuntu now. It would be great if someone could give me step by step instructions for a newbie on how to get my normal lubuntu back again. The "base-files" may be causing some kind of a problem. The "base-files" are being updated from the Trisquel repo.

Comment: Here is the full apt-cache policy:                                                             
  Installed: 1.8.16-0ubuntu3.2
  Candidate: 1.8.16-0ubuntu3.2
  Version table:
 *** 1.8.16-0ubuntu3.2 500
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.8.16-0ubuntu3 500
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety/main amd64 Packages
     1.8.3p1-1ubuntu3.7 500
        500 http://mirror.fsf.org/trisquel toutatis-updates/main amd64 Packages

Comment: if you updated base files from trisquel then you now have triquel not ubuntu. the easiest fix is to reinstall ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and probably due to the same mistake (adding a PPA to install IceCat). I've solved it by following answer https://askubuntu.com/a/733383/767716 which instructs you to reinstall base_files from https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/base-files

You should look in section `Built files`, `Files resulting from this build`, something starting with `base-files_` and ending in `.deb`

After downloading it, again following the instructions, you should 
run:

```
sudo dpkg -i /your/path/to/base-files_*.deb
```

And make a test run with:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall base-files
```

After that, I needed to change some files, for example, remove and re-add items under `/etc/sources-list.d` as some of them were pointing to the trisquel/toutatis version.